# Prove that $\nabla_\mu G^{\mu\nu} = 0$

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, general-relativity

I have Einstein's Equation

> $$\large G_{\mu\nu} = 8\pi GT_{\mu\nu}$$

And I know that when I have a vector say $S^\sigma$ then

> $$\large \nabla_\mu S^\sigma = \partial_\mu S^\sigma + \Gamma^\sigma_{\mu\lambda}S^\lambda$$

But I am not sure what
$$\large \nabla_\mu G^{\mu\nu}$$
would be with two indices. Would anyone mind showing me?

---

EDIT:

Would it look something like this?
$$\nabla_\mu G^{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu G^{\mu\nu} + \Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha\mu}G^{\alpha\nu} + \Gamma^{\nu}_{\alpha\mu}G^{\mu\alpha}$$
And if so then why would these three terms become zero?

Comment: This is physics question, so...

Comment: @TakahiroWaki. ... but also mathematics.

Comment: You can see standard general relativity text such as Sean Carroll’s or Hawking’s Large Scale Structure of Space-time for more mathematical flavour.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is called [covariant derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative). Indeed you need to write a term with Christoffel symbol for each index. For covariant derivative of a tensor field, you do:
$$
\nabla_\mu T_{kl}^{ij} = \partial_\mu T_{kl}^{ij} + \Gamma^{i}_{\alpha\mu}T_{kl}^{\alpha j} + \Gamma^{j}_{\alpha\mu}T_{kl}^{i\alpha}
-\Gamma^{\alpha}_{k\mu}T_{\alpha l}^{ij}
-\Gamma^{\alpha}_{l\mu}T_{k\alpha}^{ij}.
$$
Note sign $+$ for contravariant (upper) indices and sign $-$ for covariant (lower) indices.

After you have written the contravariant derivative, you can contract it on the desired indices.

Your expression in EDIT has several index problems (you should have only one upper index $\nu$ in each term, all other indices should go in pairs, one top, one bottom).

$$
\nabla_\mu G^{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu G^{\mu\nu} + \Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha\mu}G^{\alpha\nu} + \Gamma^{\nu}_{\alpha\mu}G^{\mu\alpha}$$

Comment: Ahh thank you I just get mixed up in the indices. So, with this result, these three terms should be zero. Do you see why?

Comment: $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$ is just a conservation law for stress-energy tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: Nice answer ..... +1

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Vasily is true and is enough. This is just an explanation:$$\Large{\nabla_\mu T_{\color{purple}k\color{green}l}^{\color{red}i\color{blue}j} = \partial_\mu T_{kl}^{ij} + \color{red}{\Gamma^{i}_{\alpha\mu}T_{kl}^{\alpha j}} + \color{blue}{\Gamma^{j}_{\alpha\mu}T_{kl}^{i\alpha}}
-{\color{purple}{\Gamma^{\alpha}_{k\mu}T_{\alpha l}^{ij}}}
-\color{green}{\Gamma^{\alpha}_{l\mu}T_{k\alpha}^{ij}}.}$$

Comment: nice! I always forget about color options

Comment: @VasilyMitch I said your answer is enough and is correct!